# appplication failed when try to use one module classes in another module?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have any modules in my spring-application on maven

First module build and I have war

Another Second module needs to import classes from a first.

Using this article [this](https://eureka.ykyuen.info/2009/10/30/maven-dependency-on-jarwar-package/)

I added this in first pom.xml

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                    <classesClassifier>classes</classesClassifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

And after builing there is jar file in directory

Than I added dependency in second module

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ru.myProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProject-webapp</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <classifier>classes</classifier>
</dependency>
```

and build all together
So, there are jar files in ear archive in lib folder, but when try to start - there is error message without logs.

Can you help me to fix it or get idea?

May be the root cause in that, second application already contained own spring-application context and initialization?

Comment: You cannot use a war as a dependency.

Comment: What maven command you were using to build your 1st maven module?